# Adding cells and setting their format at the same time with batchUpdate and appendCells using python and spreadsheets api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to populate a sheet with values and some formatting. From what I've read I found out that batchUpdate and appendCells should do the work. Unfortunately I've encountered an error which I'm not able to fix. Here's my code:

```
sheet_values = []
for row in ws:
    row_data = {'values': []}
    for cell in row:
        row_data['values'].append({
            'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': cell.value},
            'userEnteredFormat': {'horizontalAlignment': 'LEFT'}
        })
    sheet_values.append(row_data)

request_data = {"requests": [
    {
        "addSheet": {
            "properties": {
                "title": f'sheet_name'
            }
        },
        "appendCells": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "fields": "userEnteredValue, userEnteredFormat",
            "rows": sheet_values
        }
    }
]}
```

And here's the error messege:

```
"Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'appendCells'". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'requests[0]', 'description': "Invalid value at 'requests[0]' (oneof), oneof field 'kind' is already set. Cannot set 'appendCells'"}]}]"
```

I've tried to look for some solution by myself but I didn't find anything helpfull. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to insert a new sheet and also want to put `userEnteredValue` and `userEnteredFormat` with one API call using "Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate" of Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- `addSheet` and `appendCells` are required to use separate requests in `requests`.
- In your showing request body, `appendCells` uses `"sheetId": 0`. In this case, the inserted sheet is not used. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
request_data = {"requests": [
    {
        "addSheet": {
            "properties": {
                "title": f'sheet_name'
            }
        },
        "appendCells": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "fields": "userEnteredValue, userEnteredFormat",
            "rows": sheet_values
        }
    }
]}
```

##### To:

```
request_data = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "addSheet": {"properties": {"title": f"sheet_name", "sheetId": 12345}},
        },
        {
            "appendCells": {
                "sheetId": 12345,
                "fields": "userEnteredValue, userEnteredFormat",
                "rows": sheet_values,
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

- In this modification, the new sheet ID is given like `12345` when a new sheet is inserted. And, `appendCells` is used using the sheet ID of `12345`.

#### Note:

- If you want to use `appendCells` to `"sheetId": 0` isntead of the inserted sheet, please modify the above script.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddSheetRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest)